# CALL arguments (omitted? literal?)

Tags: cobol

I have the following COBOL subroutine that accepts a string, a length, and a "boolean" argument. The subroutine displays the string without the trailing blanks. The length is provided in the event that the input string's full length is different than the storage used in the subroutine for the string argument. The "boolean" indicates whether there should be a line advance after displaying the string.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. Display-String.

   DATA DIVISION.
   LOCAL-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  i                   PIC 9(3).
   01  Len                 PIC 9(3).

   LINKAGE SECTION.
   01  LS-Input-String     PIC X(255).
   01  LS-Input-Length     PIC 9(3).
   01  LS-Advancing        PIC X.
       88  LS-Advance      VALUE 'T' WHEN SET TO FALSE 'F'.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING LS-Input-String, LS-Input-Length,
           LS-Advancing.
       MOVE LENGTH OF LS-Input-String TO Len

       IF ADDRESS OF LS-Input-Length NOT = NULL THEN
           MOVE FUNCTION MIN(LS-Input-Length Len) TO Len
       END-IF

       PERFORM VARYING i FROM Len BY -1
           UNTIL i LESS THAN 1 OR LS-Input-String(i:1) NOT = ' '
       END-PERFORM

       IF i > ZERO
           IF LS-Advance THEN
               DISPLAY LS-Input-String(1:i)
           ELSE
               DISPLAY LS-Input-String(1:i) WITH NO ADVANCING
           END-IF
       ELSE
           IF LS-Advance THEN
               DISPLAY ' '
           END-IF
       END-IF
       GOBACK.
```

This works fine when I call it as:

```
MOVE LENGTH OF WS-My-String TO WS-Length
CALL 'Display-String' USING WS-My-String, WS-Length, 'F'
```

But I get erroneous results for this (the subroutine doesn't get `10` but blanks or something):

```
CALL 'Display-String' USING WS-My-String, 10, 'F'
```

So it's not accepting a literal for the second argument, even though it interprets the 3rd argument literal fine.

The random questions I came up with while writing this subroutine are:

1. Are literals even allowed as arguments in a `CALL`? I've read through documentation but having trouble figuring that out. I haven't found examples of literals, but no explicit statements to the contrary. I'm suspecting that passing `'F'` literally is wrong but "happens to work".
2. Is there a better way of handling strings of various lengths in a function like this?
3. Is there a more canonical way of issuing a line feed to the output besides `DISPLAY ' '`, and without displaying a space?
4. Ideally, I'd like to be able to omit an argument and let defaults take over in the `CALL`, but I got some kind of memory reference error when I attempted to do something like: `CALL 'Display-String' USING OMITTED, 0, 'F'`. I read some documentation on `OMITTED` but not understanding how to make it work.

I'm using `cobc (OpenCOBOL) 1.1.0` on Linux version 3.9.10-100.fc17.i686.PAE (Fedora 17).

Comment: @BillWoodger very sorry. I added it to my question.

Comment: If you want the possibility of the LS-Input-String to be omitted, you'll need to use the ADDRESS OF code similar to what you have for the length already. You're being hindered by a compiler bug. 2.0 is better, I think, but not fully fixed. It will be soon. Probably. Have a look here, for instance: https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/discussion/help/thread/210c3831/#572c Until the bug is fixed, you're going to get some results which don't relate to what you are actually doing.

Comment: @BillWoodger thanks a bunch. I might forgo making the first argument omittable. It was an experiment and not really useful. Originally, I misunderstood how OMITTED worked and thought it would use the default values indicated in the subroutine link storage. I think I'll crank along and get 2.0 working. I've built it, but it's giving me some grief about `libcob.so.4` at the moment. I'll figure that out. I know it's not a code review site, but if I'm doing anything else ridiculous, I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Updated my answer. We can start removing old comments which are actioned, keep things tidy.

Comment: @BillWoodger thanks. I got GnuCOBOL 2.0 running. I just realized I was doing something rather stupid with the literal arguments: passing a string whose length didn't match the PIC in the subroutine's Linkage section. I can pass a variable that has a different length PIC and deal with it via the length argument, but literal won't work that way.

Comment: `FUNCTION LENGTH` will work with a literal. It does mean specifying the literal twice, so far from ideal. Also forgot to mention GnuCOBOL (and OpenCOBOL) has a TRIM function, amongst a wider range of intrinsic FUNCTIONs than is usual. You can also have User Defined Functions. Then we get back to the trouble with that bug, and also the definition of parameters to a UDF.

Comment: Yeah I gathered `LENGTH` would work with literal. But if I pass a literal into the subroutine that's less than the `PIC`, it gives me some odd results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CALL` statement has three options for the USING: `BY REFERENCE`; `BY CONTENT`; `BY VALUE`; `OMITTED`. OK, four then counting that last one.

They default when specified is BY REFERENCE. The latest option specified refers to the following items on the CALL ... USING ... until another option appears.

Applying those to what you have coded, all your USING items are BY REFERENCE.

Yes, literals are allowed in CALL statements. Literals can only be used BY CONTENT or BY VALUE. So your CALL should be:

```
CALL 'Display-String'          USING BY REFERENCE 
                                         WS-My-String
                                     BY CONTENT 
                                         10 
                                     BY CONTENT 
                                         'F'
```

Or:

```
CALL 'Display-String'          USING BY REFERENCE 
                                         WS-My-String
                                     BY VALUE 
                                         10 
                                     BY VALUE 
                                         'F'
```

If you use BY VALUE you'd also have to specify BY VALUE on the matching PROCEDURE DIVISION USING ... (or ENTRY ... USING ...) item.

However, that is not the end of your story for the literal, because there is a bug. I'd suggest you consider upgrading to GnuCOBOL (the new name for OpenCOBOL) 2.0. You can find discussion of this issue in the GnuCOBOL discussion area at SourceForge.Net. It will be fixed. If you're keen, you can fix it yourself and get that included in the source...

Should cover questions one and two.

Third, interesting question. Not a canonical-for-COBOL way, as COBOL itself does not have line-feeds and such-like. A good question for the GnuCOBOL area. You can DISPLAY a hexadecimal literal of the appropriate value, but that won't be transportable. Various COBOL compilers have language extensions on DISPLAY. Whether any can be used when there is no data to DISPLAY, I don't know. There is a Z-literal, which is a literal "terminated" by a binary-zero, but I don't think the literal-content can be "missing". Others will have opinions and ideas.

Fourth, you should be able to use OMITTED on your CALL. You can't use OMITTED for a BY VALUE item, but it can be used for BY REFERENCE and BY CONTENT items.

Being able to use it also means being able to deal with it in your CALLed program. If you CALL your program with the string OMITTED your program will fail, as it is assuming that there is a field/value there to access, and there won't be.

---

OK, some review.

```
PROCEDURE DIVISION USING LS-Input-String, LS-Input-Length,
           LS-Advancing.
```

Commas in code do nothing. If you want to highlight separateness:

```
PROCEDURE DIVISION            USING LS-Input-String
                                    LS-Input-Length
                                    LS-Advancing
                                    .
```

If someone leaves `,,` lying around by accident, someone else may think "it must mean something".

```
   MOVE LENGTH OF LS-Input-String TO Len

   IF ADDRESS OF LS-Input-Length NOT = NULL THEN
       MOVE FUNCTION MIN(LS-Input-Length Len) TO Len
   END-IF
```

There are two ways to get at the length of an identifier: `LENGTH OF`; `FUNCTION LENGTH`. The latter allows this instead:

```
   IF ADDRESS OF LS-Input-Length NOT = NULL
       MOVE FUNCTION MIN ( 
                           LS-Input-Length 
                           FUNCTION  LENGTH ( 
                                              LS-Input-String 
                                            ) 
                         ) 
                                    TO Len
   END-IF
```

However:

```
   MOVE LENGTH OF LS-Input-String TO Len

   IF ADDRESS OF LS-Input-Length NOT = NULL THEN
       IF LS-Input-Length LESS THAN Len
           MOVE LS-Input-Length TO Len
       END-IF
   END-IF
```

Is, to me, clearer and will perform better if you happen to be doing lots of them.

I don't jam things together. On other compilers you'd get at least some diagnostic message from this:

```
LS-Input-String(i:1)
```

I'd make it, and similar:

```
LS-Input-String ( i : 1 )
```

At a minimum there should be blanks around the brackets themselves.

To check for entirely blank I... check for entirely blank, but earlier. Save the loop in that case, simplifies the terminal condition for the loop:

```
   IF LS-Input-String EQUAL TO SPACE
       IF LS-Advance 
           DISPLAY ' '
       END-IF
   ELSE
       PERFORM VARYING i FROM Len BY -1
           UNTIL LS-Input-String ( i : 1 ) 
                  NOT EQUAL TO SPACE
       END-PERFORM
       IF LS-Advance THEN
           DISPLAY LS-Input-String ( 1 : i )
       ELSE
           DISPLAY LS-Input-String ( 1 : i ) 
             WITH NO ADVANCING
       END-IF
   END-IF
```

I'd put those "legs" into paragraphs and PERFORM them, but the effect is the same.

```
   GOBACK.

   GOBACK
   .
```

In the PROCEDURE DIVISION I only code full-stops/periods at the end of a label or SECTION or on a line of their own. When moving code about or inserting new code, you never have to concern yourself with moving a full-stop/period.

I'd also do something slightly different which has a bigger impact.

The way you have coded it, if the length of the string is OMITTED, then the CALLing program must supply and identifier of 255 bytes. If it does not, then your CALLed program will be picking up stuff it shouldn't.

If that is what you intend, then OK. If not, I'd consider not making the length optional, and using the length for the actual field, with `OCCURS DEPENDING ON`.

```
01  LS-Input-String.
    05  FILLER OCCURS 0 TO 255 TIMES
        DEPENDING ON LS-Input-Length.
        10  FILLER                         PIC X.
01  LS-Input-Length                        PIC 9(3).

...

    MOVE LS-Input-Length            TO Len
```

Now, when you have a zero-length input,

```
           DISPLAY LS-Input-String
```

Is doing it more like you want. A new line, but not even a space on the old line.

Comment: Thanks. Any time I try `BY VALUE` (noting it both in the `CALL` and in the subroutine's `PROCEDURE DIVISION` declaration as needed), I get and "Attempt to reference unallocated memory". I tried `CALL 'Display-String' USING BY CONTENT 'xyz     ', BY CONTENT 8, BY CONTENT 'T'` and it displays a blank, whereas I would have expected `xyz`.

Comment: I'll take your advice on the GnuCobol upgrade. The version I have was the latest grabbed with `yum install cobol`, so I'll need to install from source probably. How do I get 2.0? SourceForge.net says, it's *on its way to pre-release*...

Comment: @lurker I got mine here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/open-cobol/files/gnu-cobol/2.0/ If you have trouble with anything, ask away in the discussion area.

Comment: This is excellent. I wish I could upvote it again. :) I'm just getting started and had only a glancing familiarity with making a data item that varied in length somehow (using the `OCCURS` and `DEPENDING ON`). I'm a little schizo with spaces around parens and arguments. More commonly, I would have written, `LS-Input-String( 1 : i )`, as in some languages, having the space before the open paren can be an issue.

Comment: would there happen to be any generally accepted set of coding standards for COBOL documented anywhere?

Comment: No :-) The is the start of a recent discussion, you-know-where.

Answer (score 2):

In Cobol, the calling program is compiled completely separately from the called module, there are no header files like in C. So when compiling the calling program, the Compiler **does not** know the format of the **parameters** of the program being called. The Cobol Compiler will format parameters based on a set of rules it has. The format the Cobol Compiler decides on could be different from what the calling program is expecting.

So when in doubt, use a variable on the call

In your case, I suspect

```
CALL 'Display-String' USING WS-My-String, '010', 'F'
```

would work

Comment: Bruce, thanks. I actually tried playing with a literal string for the first argument. Although not a useful use case, it wasn't giving me expected results, either (would compile but display pieces of arbitrary data from memory). Using a string for the numeric argument sometimes produces results, but, again, not expected results.

Comment: I played with this further and, yes, if I pass the number in as `'010'` it does work! Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to write the subroutine so that one can pass a literal number just as a number?

Comment: I would also work when the quotes are omitted, i.e. `010`, I guess. Futhermore, with AcuCOBOL there's a compiler option to convert specified values to numeric values when the receiving field is a numeric field. For example, when I have `SOMEVAR PIC 9(4)` in a subprogram, then `CALL "Subprogram" USING 7` would convert the 7 (it's actually a `"###7"` where # is a space) to 0007.